# Installing phpmyadmin in ubuntu 20 with PHP 5.6

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-20.04

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/autoload.php on line 2
> [Tue Mar 02 15:31:53.350649 2021] [:error] [pid 78433] [client ::1:54326] PHP Warning:  require_once(PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/autoload.php on line 2

I installed php 5.6 version and tried to install phpmyadmin. While opening http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ I am getting the issue

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using and how have you installed it?

Comment: I got the same issue when installing PHP 5.6 (and all other versions) on a new system with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on a Ubuntu 20.04 with a PHP 7.4.3. The module autoload.php is located in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/ but this path is unknown by PHP (in your case the include path have only this as per your error message: include_path='/usr/share/phpmyadmin').

To fix this I edited the php include_path in the php.ini file in (/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini) so that it includes /usr/share/php/ at the end. e.g:

```
include_path = ".:/php/includes:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/lib/php/:/usr/share/php/"
```

(i just added :/usr/share/php/ to my existing include_path string)

Then after a restart of the apache server my phpmyadmin page loaded properly

Answer (score 1):

First Idea: you would have to set the `include_path` to  `.:/usr/share/php/` where the `MoTranslator` Library is located.

But this didn't work for PHP5.6 either, since the shared libraries will be for a newer version.

I solved it by manually [downloading an older version compatible with PHP 5.5 to 7.4 and MySQL/MariaDB 5.5 and newer](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) without using the Debian package system.

Comment: Manual installation worked for me as well. Now I have Ubuntu 20.04.6 + MySQL 8 + PHP 5.6 + [phpMyAdmin 4.9.11](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.9.11/) + Apache 2.4.41 (with Apache `php5.6` module enabled). It was enough [uncompressing and pasting](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install-1) the entire `.tar.gz` folder into `/var/www/html` or whatever directory your Apache is serving. No need even to create a configuration file (although you can do).